# Yahoo! LDA Implementation Questions

Tags: yahoo, lda, topic-modeling

All,

I have been running Y!LDA (https://github.com/shravanmn/Yahoo_LDA) on a set of documents and the results look great (or at least what I would expect). Now I want to use the resulting topics to perform a reverse query against the corpus. Does anyone know if the 3 human readable text files that are generated after the learntopics executable is run is the final output for this library? If so, is that what I need to parse to perform my queries? I am stuck with a little shoulder shrugging at this point...

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

If LDA is working the way I think it is (I use a java implementation, so explanations may vary) then what you get out are the three following things:

1. P(word,concept) -- The probability of getting a word given a concept. So, when LDA finishes figuring out what concepts exist within the corpus, this P(w,c) will tell you (in theory) which words map to which concepts.

   A very naive method of determining concepts would be to load this file into a matrix and combine all these probabilities for all possible concepts for a test document in some method (add, multiply, Root-mean-squared) and rank order the concepts.

   Do note that the above method does not recognize the various biases introduced by weakly represented topics or dominating topics in LDA. To accommodate that, you need more complicated algorithms (Gibbs sampling, for instance), but this will get you *some* results.
2. P(concept,document) -- If you are attempting to find the intrinsic concepts in the documents in the corpus, you would look here. You can use the documents as examples of documents that have a particular concept distribution, and compare your documents to the LDA corpus documents... There are uses for this, but it may not be as useful as the P(w,c).
3. Something else probably relating to the weights of words, documents, or concepts. This could be as simple as a set of concept examples with beta weights (for the concepts), or some other variables that are output from LDA. These may or may not be important depending on what you are doing. (If you are attempting to add a document to the LDA space, having the alpha or beta values -- very important.)

To answer your 'reverse lookup' question, to determine the concepts of the test document, use P(w,c) for each word w in the test document.

To determine which document is the most like the test document, determine the above concepts, then compare them to the concepts for each document found in P(c,d) (using each concept as a dimension in vector-space and then determining a cosine between the two documents tends to work alright).

To determine the similarity between two documents, same thing as above, just determine the cosine between the two concept-vectors.

Hope that helps.